# Ember + Firebase, locationtype = history

Tags: ember.js, firebase, fullpage.js, firebase-hosting

I am hosting my ember app with firebase and would like to use locationType=history (no hash in url) as i am also using fullpage.js, which uses the #.

So my question is: can i configure firebase to only listen for the base-url?

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for are so-called rewrites.

From the [Firebase documentation for rewrites](https://www.firebase.com/docs/hosting/guide/url-redirects-rewrites.html#section-rewrites):

> Use a rewrite when you want to show the same content for multiple URLs.
>
> URL rewrites can be specified by defining a `rewrites` section in the `firebase.json` file:

```
"rewrites": [ {
  "source": "**",
  "destination": "/index.html"
} ]
```

Be sure to read the docs, because there is a lot more that you can do with these rules.